# A strange macro definition c++

Tags: c++, macros, string-concatenation

I met this error when compiling an open source project:

```
/usr/local/include/dbus-1.0/dbus/dbus-protocol.h:459:126: error: invalid suffix on literal; C++11 requires a space between literal and identifier [-Wreserved-user-defined-literal]
#define DBUS_INTROSPECT_1_0_XML_DOCTYPE_DECL_NODE "<!DOCTYPE node PUBLIC \""DBUS_INTROSPECT_1_0_XML_PUBLIC_IDENTIFIER"\"\n\""DBUS_INTROSPECT_1_0_XML_SYSTEM_IDENTIFIER"\">\n"
```

This is fixed by changing the above macro definition:

```
-#define DBUS_INTROSPECT_1_0_XML_DOCTYPE_DECL_NODE "<!DOCTYPE node PUBLIC \""DBUS_INTROSPECT_1_0_XML_PUBLIC_IDENTIFIER"\"\n\""DBUS_INTROSPECT_1_0_XML_SYSTEM_IDENTIFIER"\">\n"
+#define DBUS_INTROSPECT_1_0_XML_DOCTYPE_DECL_NODE "<!DOCTYPE node PUBLIC \"" DBUS_INTROSPECT_1_0_XML_PUBLIC_IDENTIFIER "\"\n\"" DBUS_INTROSPECT_1_0_XML_SYSTEM_IDENTIFIER "\">\n
```

What confused me is the #define itself:

```
#define A "" B "" C ""
```

What is this?
We can use `#define` like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `#define` to define a macro that contains anything.

Whether or not this results in valid C++ code that can be compiled, when the macro gets used, is an entirely different story.

Comment: I thought dbus_protocol.h is trying to define 3 macros, isn't it ?

Comment: No, `DBUS_INTROSPECT_1_0_XML_DOCTYPE_DECL_NODE` is a macro that expands to `"<!DOCTYPE node PUBLIC \"" DBUS_INTROSPECT_1_0_XML_PUBLIC_IDENTIFIER "\"\n\"" DBUS_INTROSPECT_1_0_XML_SYSTEM_IDENTIFIER "\">\n"`.  This is fine as long as `DBUS_INTROSPECT_1_0_XML_PUBLIC_IDENTIFIER` and `DBUS_INTROSPECT_1_0_XML_SYSTEM_IDENTIFIER` are macros that expand to either nothing or string literals since adjacent string literals are merged together.

Comment: @MilesBudnek then it should be ok for compiler if the spaces are missed out

Answer (score 2):

If you use:

```
#define A "Foo" B "Bar" C "Baz"
```

`A` expands to a string whose value is a concatenation three hard coded strings and two other strings that are defined by macros `B` and `C`.

If `B` is `#define`d as `"_10_"` and `C` is `#define`d as `"_XYZ"`, then `A` expands to

```
"Foo" "_10_" "Bar" "_XYZ" "Baz"
```

which is equivalent to

```
"Foo_10_Bar_XYZBaz"
```